# Including use of Mask in Raster > Vector conversion in QGIS

Tags: qgis, convert, qgis-modeler, masking

The Polygonize (raster to vector) tool in QGIS Raster > Conversion menu allows for the use of a mask, however this option is not available in the Processing Modeler. What would be the best way to incorporate this functionality into the model?

For some context, I am converting a single-band raster to polygons using itself as a mask (values range from 0-1).

Answer (score 2):

You could incorporate the following tools into your model:

1. **Clip raster by mask layer** tool.
2. Then use the **Polygonize (raster to vector)** tool on the output of Step 1.